# Google Analytics - relatively compare segments

Tags: google-analytics, advanced-segments

Is there a way to relatively compare two different segments in Google Analytics over time?

For example, I'd like to see the percentage of the segment mobile traffic (segment A) which comes from search (segment B) over time to answer the question: what part (%) of my mobile traffic has come from search engines over time? (has the contribution of search traffic to mobile increased or decreased)

The only way I know to answer questions like these is to plot both segments and see whether the lines are getting closer to eachother or further away from eachother.

Comment: Yes i think Marcin is right. You can export your data in excel then divide the total number of mobile visits, number of mobile visits from search over time and then plot it.

Answer (score 2):

So, in an absence of a metric like "visits from search", what you're looking for is basically DIVIDING one curve over another one. I've spent a lot time trying to do this myself and don't think you're able to do it in the UI (maybe with the reporting API).

As a workaround, I suggest you export these two curves (total number of mobile visits, number of mobile visits from search over time) to Excel/Google Drive, divide these two rows by one another and then plot it. I believe this is how most GA post-analysis is done in the industry anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Many reports in Google Analytics will now let you compare up to four segments.  All you have to do is add the segments that you want to compare to your report.

For example, I have added several segments to this Audience Overview report:

[image: compare segments]

Comment: Thanks Stephen. However, unfortunately this is not a good way to **relatively** compare segments, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: What does relatively mean to you?  I would say that seeing the different lines on a graph allows one to compare how they are doing relative to each other very easily.

Comment: Imo comparing how the lines move by eye only allows you to see large differences, as I mentioned: "the only way I know to answer questions like these is to plot both segments and see whether the lines are getting closer to eachother or further away from eachother." - I would like to plot one relative to the other - I suppose excel is the way to go atm

Answer (score -2):

## Just drag segments into empty boxes

Reference: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123906?hl=en

[image: Just drag segments into empty boxes]

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem